# merging two data frames with different columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two tables that I want to merge:

Data.frame A:

| DATUM | CP | MNOZSTVI | CLOSE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-30 | USD | 18 | NA |
| 2021-07-30 | CZK | 2991 | NA |
| 2021-07-30 | EUR | 0 | NA |

Data.frame B:

| DATUM | CP | CLOSE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-30 | USD | 21,4 |
| 2021-07-30 | CZK | 1 |
| 2021-07-30 | EUR | 25 |

Desired data.frame:

| DATUM | CP | MNOZSTVI | CLOSE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-30 | USD | 18 | 21,4 |
| 2021-07-30 | CZK | 2991 | 1 |
| 2021-07-30 | EUR | 0 | 25 |

I would like to do that using join function from dplyr. I tried it using full_join:

```
desired.data.frame<- A %>%
  full_join(B)
```

But it does not work as I want.
Thank you for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `left_join` and then select the columns:

```
library(dplyr)
df_A %>% 
    left_join(df_B, by="CP") %>% 
    select(DATUM = DATUM.x, CP, MNOZSTVI, CLOSE=CLOSE.y)
```

Or  thanks to akrun ,

```
df_A %>% select(-CLOSE) %>% left_join(df_B)
```

Output:

```
 DATUM      CP    MNOZSTVI CLOSE
  <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 2021-07-30 USD         18  21.4
2 2021-07-30 CZK       2991   1  
3 2021-07-30 EUR          0  25
```

data:

```
df_A <- tribble(
~DATUM,     ~CP,    ~MNOZSTVI, ~CLOSE,
"2021-07-30",   "USD",  18, NA,
"2021-07-30",   "CZK",  2991, NA,
"2021-07-30",   "EUR",  0, NA)

df_B <- tribble(
    ~DATUM,     ~CP,    ~CLOSE,
    "2021-07-30",   "USD",  21.4,
    "2021-07-30",   "CZK",  1,
    "2021-07-30",   "EUR",  25)
df_A
```

Comment: Or may do the `select` before `df_A %>% select(-CLOSE) %>% left_join(df_B)`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks master!